# How to order by filtered count on relation in prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I want to order by a filtered count on a relation. eg. In a model like this:

```
model UserFollow {
  Follower    User   @relation("Follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  String
  Following   User   @relation("Following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId String


  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}

model User {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  name      String   @default("")

  Followers    UserFollow[]   @relation("Following")
  Followings   UserFollow[]   @relation("Follower")
}
```

I want to list a user followers ordered to show mutual follows on top. Now I can query my table like this:

```
followers = await prisma.userFollow.findMany({
  where: {
    followingId: targetUserId,
  },
  include: {
    Follower: {
      include: {
        Followers: {
          where: {
            followerId: currentUserID,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  orderBy: [
    {
      Follower: {
        Followers: {
          _count: 'desc',
        },
      },
    }
  ],
});
```

to list followers by their follower count. I want to sort by the number of followers filtered in the include clause (which is 1 if currentUser followed the targetUser and 0 otherwise). Is it possible without backing off to raw queries?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible with a Prisma query :/. You're going to have to use raw queries or sort inside your application.